# How can i clean up an array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array which is a collection of all the sizes that a product could possible be, this is used by Magento using a EAV Database Structure so the array is formatted like this

```
entity_id => 'text',

28709 => 'L'
28734 => 'S'
28732 => 'XL'
28721 => '22B'
28705 => '16'
```

what i have posted is only a small sample, the array gets to be quite large (over 10,000)

now i have another array formatted like this

```
size_entity_id => product_entity_id

28734 => '7314895'
28709 => '7365374'
28732 => '7382004'
```

how i uses these 2 arrays is that i do a for each (in the format of `foreach($sizeArray as $_index => $_value)`) of the first array and check if that index exists in the second array using `isset`

now i figured i can improve on the code without having to recode someone else work by cleaning up the first array since the 2nd array has only ever been at most the size of 10

i am wondering if there is a nice simple solution to cleaning up my first array without having to do something like this

```
foreach($sizeArray as $_index => $_value)
{
    if(!isset($products[$_index]))
    {
        unset($sizeArray[$_index])
    }
}
```

since if i do this i'll be going though all the values in the array where ass if i didn't do this and kept how the code worked now 95% of the time it won't go though the entire array (the other 5% would be in a size was near the end of the array it would still go though the array and be close to the end)

NOTE: how the code works is fine but since i didn't develop it i don't want to recode up someone else work when i don't fully understand it and all i've been tasked with doing if finding places where i can improve on it (ie, reducing the array being worked with from 10,000 to 10)

EDIT: ok, i seemed to have missed one thing, the first array, as you can see with the first 3 values are L, S and XL which represent Large, Small and Extra Large, there is some code before the foreach i described which sorts this so that S will be before L this way we start at the smallest size regardless of what sizes a product may have, because of the sample i  have taken it fails to reflect the potential gaps in the array if i left the code as it is, here is a sample of the sorted array between sizes 16 and 17

```
##### => '16'
##### => '16A'
##### => '16B'
##### => '16C'
##### => '16S'
##### => '16M'
##### => '16L'
##### => '16Â½'
##### => '16>'
##### => '17'
```

now i don't know how the sorting is done but apart from the fact it's sorting almost 10,000 items in the array (since it's a function used throughout someone else is handling that since it's coming up as a problem in their work and with the code i'm looking at seems that it's only used to control the direction of the loop iteration) if the second array had a size 16 and a size 17 and the first array wasn't cleaned up it would process at 16, skip though every single value till it gets to 17 which means failing that `isset` check 8 times before is true again, and this is is i think the smallest example, the problem with magento is that all the sizes for every time of product is grouped together even though 2/3s of the catalog would use XS -> XL kind of scaling for sizes

Comment: It there actually a use case where you need to find the product_entity_id's for all size_entity_id's at once.  In other words are you really going to display all that data on a page at once? mEven if you do need all at once, is this data actually derived from a database, as it seems a trivial table join would solve this problem for you.

Comment: I'm unsure exactly why you would want to do what you're asking for.  It seems like you want to throw out all the data from the first array while you're dealing with the second array.  Then what happens when you move on to the next product.  Maybe We need more information as to how this data is used.

Comment: @MikeBrant well this part of the code was developed quite some time ago and the person who made it was probably trying to the existing collections and didn't know how to add joins to a collection and as i said i rather not recode someone else work especially if it works since previous experience as shown me that if you try and rebuild something that works just to make it a bit faster it'll break and the person who made the code no longer is with us so i would have to read though undocumented code before i can be confident that my theories wont break the entire thing, reducing this array wont

Comment: I might be the only one, but I think we might be better able to help you if you post some actual code.  Maybe you need to ask a different question as your original question appears to have been answered.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can go in another direction:

```
$newSizeArray = array();
foreach ($products as $i => $index)
    if (isset($sizeArray[$index]))
        $newSizeArray[$index] = $sizeArray[$index];
$sizeArray = $newSizeArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array_intersect_key() function which gives you the result of your two for() loops in one call.

http://www.php.net/function.array-intersect-key

It probably will be faster since that's written in C or C++ opposed to you running a PHP for() loop.

I don't think you have very many choices, although Ilya Bursov answer is good too. That loop goes through only 10 times.

Comment: Doesn't Ilya Bursov's answer technically go through the array more than once?  I'm not 100% sure, but I imagine the `isset` function requires some sort of traversal.

Comment: He does it with the tiny array, so it is dearly optimized. More or less, if you know that a set is much smaller than the other, you can loop through the items of that smaller set and test whether those items appear in the other. All the other items are ignored. So if `$products` has 3 items, you'll do just 3 isset() calls. Pretty well optimized.

Comment: Right, but doesn't the isset call itself do some sort of iteration through the larger array?  Maybe not directly, but it has to search something to find if that index exists in the larger array. What kinds of search depends on the internal code of the isset function, but it has to be there.

Comment: The search for a key in PHP arrays, from what I remember, is very fast because it uses a form of hash. Much faster than iterating all the entries one by one.

Comment: I see.  So there is some overhead, but not as much for a manual iteration.  Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Removing unwanted elements from the first array is quite easy:

```
$sizeArray = array_intersect_key($sizeArray, $products);
```

The order of the arrays as passed to the function is important. See the entry for `array_intersect_keys` on php.net [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

I will add a question in an answer though: I'm not sure if doing this in your case would really help you much with overhead unless you repeatedly us the first array, in which case, you'd probably need to retain ALL the data.  Maybe you need more of an explanation?